# Height and width of a SWF file in html

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, mxmlc

In the following code Only the button image has been embeded into the flex code.But in the html object or embed tag why the height and width has to be specified.Even though for this is a normal button if we do not specify the height and width there seems to  be some error

`html`

```
<div align="center">
    <br />
    <div style="display:block;width:100px;height:100px;" id="audio" 
        class="testsound" align="center"/>
    <p class="clickable">
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
        width="400" height="100" id="myMovieName">
            <param name="movie" value="/media/players/testsound.swf"/>
            <param name="soundurl" value="/media/players/music.mp3"/>
            <param name="quality" value="high"/>
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
            <embed width="100" height="100" href="/media/players/testsound.swf" 
                src="/media/players/testsound.swf" 
                flashvars="soundUrl=/media/players/music.mp3" 
                quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
                name="myMovieName" loop="false" align=""
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
            </embed>
        </object>
    </p>
</div>
```

`MXML`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- embed/EmbedSound.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import flash.media.*; 

            public var snd:Sound = new sndCls() as Sound; 
            public var sndChannel:SoundChannel;

            public function playSound():void {
                sndChannel=snd.play();
            }   

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Image id="loader1" click="playSound();"
        source="@Embed(source='/opt/cloodon/site/media/img/speaker.gif')" />
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should specify in your main mxml the width and height of your `Application` even though it contains but a clickable image! 
If you'd like your page to have a flex image (button??) of `width: 400px` and `height: 100px`, then your `Application` tag must look like:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="100">
```

And nonetheless, in your html you should have both your `object` and `embed` tags to have the same `width` and `height`, and you should specify a value to your `embed` tag's `align` attribute as well, eg: `align="middle"`.

Your `object` tag should look similar to

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
    width="400" height="100" id="myMovieName"
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
    <param name="movie" value="/media/players/testsound.swf"/>
    <param name="soundurl" value="/media/players/music.mp3"/>
    <param name="quality" value="high"/>
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <!-- the embed tag does not have href attribute  -->
    <embed width="400" height="100"  
        src="/media/players/testsound.swf" 
        flashvars="soundUrl=/media/players/music.mp3" 
        quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
        name="myMovieName" loop="false" align="middle"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </embed>
</object>
```

**Other**
Where is your sndClass declared? If you have that mp3 embedded, your script tag should contain:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.SoundAsset; 

        [Embed('/media/players/music.mp3')]
        private var _sound:Class;
        public var snd:SoundAsset = new _sound() as SoundAsset;

        public var sndChannel:SoundChannel;

        public function playSound():void {
            sndChannel=snd.play();
        }   

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

If you'd like to specify your mp3's path from html, you might look at [this post for reference](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/grabbing-flashvars-from-the-embedding-html-template/).

**Update 2**

To set the html `object`'s width and height based on your flex button's size, you should update your application mxml code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" 
    width="1" height="1" backgroundColor="#bee3f6"
    horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            //This method will change the button's label ==> width.
            public function sayWhat():void {
                var _date:Date = new Date();
                extButton.label = "It's " + (_date.getHours() + 1) + ":" + _date.getMinutes() + 
                    ((_date.getMilliseconds() % 2) == 0 ? ". nice." : ". very tired.");
            }

            public function onCreationComplete():void {
                // binds this.sayWhat to the external interface, so when from   
                // javascript is called the compiled swf object's sayWhat function,
                // it will be transferred to this.sayWhat. 
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("sayWhat", sayWhat);

                // set the flash application's size to be exact the button's size.
                this.width = extButton.width;
                this.height = extButton.height;

                try 
                {
                    // The js function: onFlashAppInited(width, height);
                    // The next line tells the external interface (the parent application:
                    // browser window), that this application has finished loading, its 
                    // ready to be used. 
                    // We're passing the button's width and height as parameters
                    // In js there has to be a global method with this name.
                    ExternalInterface.call("onFlashAppInited", extButton.width, extButton.height);
                }
                catch (e:Error)
                {
                    trace(e.message + "\n" + e.getStackTrace(), e.name);
                }
            }        

            protected function onButtonUpdateComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // if the button's size has changed, we notify the javascript to set the 
                // correct size to the object tag too.
                if ((this.width != extButton.width) || (this.height != extButton.height))
                {
                    // set the application size
                    this.width = extButton.width;
                    this.height = extButton.height;
                    // notify the js about the change
                    ExternalInterface.call("onFlashAppSizeChanged", this.width, this.height);
                }
            }

        ]]>             
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button id="extButton" label="Do something!" updateComplete="onButtonUpdateComplete(event)" />
</mx:Application>
```

Note, that initially this application is only 1x1 pixel (if less, it won't initialize!). 
In the `onCreationComplete` handler its size is changed to match the button's size.

These values (width and height) are passed to the javascript function `onFlashAppInited`, which you should also update:

```
function onFlashAppInited(width, height) {
    alert("Flash app inited!");
    appInited = true;

    onFlashAppSizeChanged(width,height);

    // remove the temporary swf container: tmp
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("tmp"));
}

function onFlashAppSizeChanged(width, height) {
    flashApp.width = width + "px";
    flashApp.height = height + "px";
}
```

Comment: I agree with u about setting height and width in mxml and html.But by default we dont know the size of a button in flex so if a default button is specified,how to know its height and width and how to set that in html..?

Comment: :-? you could try retrieving the size (width/height) of the button from your onCreationComplete method in flex, and pass it to the javascript (along the flashAppInited method as parameter). This way the javascript side will be notified about the width of your button, and can resize the swf object to have the exact same size.

Comment: K..Can u please let me know of any link of how to retrieve it..By the way i saw ur site.Though its its not functional it already cool..

Comment: I've updated the answer, based on that you'll be able to send the flex button's size to the js side whenever it changes. updated the sample as well (if you'd like to try out).

Comment: any luck so far? please let me know if you need further guidance. +1 for a question about using communication between flex and javascript.

Answer (score 7):

Height and Width in an embed tag are required attributes. Have a gander at [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) or [Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html) on the tag definition as well as [required and optional attributes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_Required_attributes).

Are you asking **why** they're required or why your page will break if you don't have them (hint, the first answer is the second question)?

**EDIT:**

You should modify the width and height attribute of the EMBED and OBJECT tags to be exactly to the size of the swf.

You can set your application width and height in the .mxml

```
<mx:Application width="300" height="200">
```

If you set the scaleMode to "noScale" you won't see any scaling in your swf.

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

If you're in Actionscript 3 (which you should be), you can set the meta-data in your main class.

i.e.

```
[SWF(width="640", height="480")]
public class MyClass extends Sprite
{
    public function MyClass()
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    }
}
```

Comment: But now from your posts it doesnt exactly suggest what should be done to fit the swf to its exact size in the html file

Comment: Ok, a couple more bits of advice in my edit above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @Dominic Tancredi's comment:
Both OBJECT and EMBED tags require WIDTH and HEIGHT attributes.